# Is `ls -l` sorting files unintuitively?

Tags: ls, sort, locale

Let me explain considering this output of `ls -l met*`:

```
% ll met*
-rw-rw-r--. 1 polemon polemon  20K 09-20 04:24 met_gs.png
-rw-rw-r--. 1 polemon polemon  20K 09-20 04:26 met_idx.png
-rw-rw-r--. 1 polemon polemon 3.9K 09-20 04:28 met_mon.png
-rw-rw-r--. 1 polemon polemon  35K 09-20 04:23 met.png
```

As you can see, I have four files, all starting with the word `met`, and then a suffix.

As you can see as well, the shortest of them `met.png` is displayed on the last line.

I assume this happens because lexicographicaly the '_' comes before the '.'.
However, this still feels wrong. Is there a way I can make `ls` print file lists like this in a more intuitive lexicographical order, like this:

```
met.png
met_gs.png
met_idx.png
met_mon.png
```

?

My version of `ls` is: »ls (GNU coreutils) 8.24«

My locale is en_US.utf8

Comment: What's your locale?  One possibility is it's Unicode/UTF-8, which treats all punctuation as equivalent.

Comment: @Mikel it's en_US.utf8. I've edited that into my question.

Comment: I don't understand what you feel is unintuitive about `gs < idx < mon < png`. That's alphabetical order: G comes before I comes before M comes before P.

Comment: `.` (46) comes before `_` (95) in ASCIIbetical order.

Comment: @Gilles simply the fact, that my eyes are easier to parse the first part and the extension, the suffix-part of the name, is out of collection, in that case. I guess it basically comes down to personal preference, but to me, seeing the '_' as initiator for a name suffix is more natural.

Comment: @user1024 That would matter in the C locale, but not in the locale polemon uses. In en_US.utf8, punctuation is not considered during the first pass, like in usual “human” sorting.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `ls -lv` for this, where `-l` is the long listing and `-v` is natural sort

```
root@vps60508:~# ls -l
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Sep 19 23:00 met_gs.png
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Sep 19 23:01 met_idx.png
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Sep 19 23:01 met_mon.png
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Sep 19 23:01 met.png
root@vps60508:~# ls -lv
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Sep 19 23:01 met.png
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Sep 19 23:00 met_gs.png
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Sep 19 23:01 met_idx.png
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Sep 19 23:01 met_mon.png
```